# Python facebook-sdk not pulling page likes

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to pull the number of likes for a Facebook page. I have two access tokens: one keeps giving me an error of "An unknown error has occurred." so I created a new one which is not able to pull the number of likes for a page.

Here's what my example code looks like (partially taken from the pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk GitHub repository):

```
import facebook
import requests
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "*********"
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "*********"
access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
user = 'BillGates'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
print profile['likes']
```

And the error I'm recieving is "Keyerror: 'likes'". (Which obviously means the key 'likes' is not in the object I created - however, I used this same code yesterday without any issues and it suddenly bugged out today with no changes to the code).

Other calls with the object work, such as:

```
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')
```

Why has the 'likes' key disappeared suddenly?

Comment: Does it work with other users? People can change their permissions, which could explain why it works one day and not another.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I've tried several different users to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So it started working again today. I did not touch anything or change any code. I used my original token which was throwing the error "An unknown error has occurred.". In-case anyone out there is wondering - **An app access token will not expire!** so creating a new token was pointless.

So the answer is: facebook API `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`